# css background transition in opera goes through black

Tags: css, opera, css-transitions

I'm just getting into CSS3 transitions (about time!) and I witness some strange behavior in Opera 11.60.

I use a transition to change an element from `background:none` to `background:#fff`. However, the transition actually goes through black/dark grey before reaching its target.

Now, I can understand why this happens - the opacity and the color are animated at the same time, and since the color used to be `none`, Opera regards it as `#000`. Looks like a bug to me.

Is there a way to fix this, save for turning off transitions in Opera for elements with `background:none`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying a transition from `background: rgba(255,255,255,0)` to `background: rgba(255,255,255,1)`? (That’s from white with zero opacity to white with full opacity.)

See e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/tajMG/

Comment: Yup, that's what I was missing - means to specify opacity. How far down the IE hole does RGBA support go, though?

Comment: What a coincidence, I’ve just launched a website that answers that very question (SELF-PROMOTION ALERT) — sadly, it’s only supported since IE9 (and Opera 10, come to that): [http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/rgba()](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/rgba())