# CSS Positioning for Glyphicon-based Navbar that Opens on Hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert a image mockup into HTML/CSS and I'm struggling to get the navbar working:

JSFiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/ZcrCc/

Full-screen JSFiddle output:

http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/ZcrCc/embedded/result/

This is the mockup of the navbar:

[image]

The idea is that normally it will only have the hamburger icon and the "Menu" text, and then when you hover, it should open downwards and display the glyphicons and text.

I'm not sure how to integrate the glyphicons into the existing `<li>` elements (Should I just use a `<br>` to split the lines?) - and then using CSS positioning so that it opens up and closes.

```
#nav > a
{
    display: none;
}
#nav li
{
    position: relative;
}

/* first level */

#nav > ul
{
    height: 3.75em;
}
    #nav > ul > li
    {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you closer. I'd make your glyph icons block elements. If you want a nice animation either use CSS3 or jQuery.

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#biography"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>Bio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#story"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>Story</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#proposal"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>Proposal</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#gallery"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#rsvp"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>RSVP</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#thedate"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>The Date</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#party"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>Party</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#thankyou"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>Thank You</a>
            </li>
        </ul> <a href="/">Menu</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
#nav > a {
    display:none;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#nav li {
    position: relative;
}
/* first level */
#nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
/* second level */
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav li ul img {
    display:block;
    min-width:100%;
}
#nav li ul li {
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wz5wn/

Comment: Good work, +1. @victorjooi I would perhaps change it to use CSS transitions and animate the height of the `li` items instead of the choppy transition with `display`. It'd mean changing the mark up slightly, but [**here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wz5wn/1/) of what I mean. I'd also give `position:fixed` to the nav so it stays on the left side and give it a white background color to differentiate

Comment: Could I ask what's the motivation behind `display: block;` and `min-width:100%` - when I do that with Glyphicons http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/THE24/2/ it upscales them all to 50x50, resulting in them being quite blurry? (I'm guessing the 50x50 is from the width of the text?)

Comment: You need to change the dimensions of the object to whatever the glyphicons are so it doesn't need to scale

Comment: If I just remove the `min-width:100%;`, that seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/THE24/3/ - however, I was wondering if there was a reason it was in the original answer. If you look at this latest JSFiddle though, I still need to figure out a way to centre everything, and the text underneath the icons.

Comment: [**Try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wz5wn/4/). To center the images I used `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @Zeaklous Thanks mate - I currently have this - http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/THE24/9/ - one problem though - when you have a background, you get black flickering lines between each <li>. This is on Chrome on OSX. I'm not sure why this is. I set every single element to white, but that didn't seem to help?

Comment: I seemed to have remedied the problem [**with this update**](http://jsfiddle.net/THE24/11/) and made a few small overall improvements. It turns out [it was a bigger issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943825/css-background-transition-in-opera-goes-through-black) than I had expected to start

Comment: @victorhooi Anything else I can help out with?